# Spring boot + JPA problem with post mapping form where is select multiple

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-thymeleaf

I have a PostMapping whith form where user can create a meeting and invite employees. My problem is that the employees are not saved to the database.
Here is my MeetingDTO:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class MeetingDto {
    private Long id;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Content could not be empty")
    private String contentOfMeeting;
    @FutureOrPresent
    private LocalDateTime startOfMeeting;
    private LocalDateTime endOfMeeting;
    private Status status;
    private List<Employee> employees;
    private Visitor visitor;
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/visitors/new-meeting")
    public String createMeetingForm(Model model) {
        List<Employee> employeeList = employeeRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("employeeList", employeeList);
        model.addAttribute("meeting", new Meeting());
        return "visitors-createAMeeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/visitors/new-meeting")
    public String saveMeeting(@ModelAttribute("meeting") MeetingDto meetingDto) {
        String nameOfVisitor;

        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            nameOfVisitor = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            nameOfVisitor = principal.toString();
        }

        Long visitorId = visitorRepository.findByEmailAddress(nameOfVisitor).getId();
        meetingDto.setVisitor(visitorRepository.findById(visitorId).orElse(null));
        meetingService.createMeeting(visitorId, meetingDto);
        return "redirect:/visitors/home";
    }
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class MeetingServiceImpl implements MeetingService {
    private MeetingRepository meetingRepository;
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    private VisitorRepository visitorRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MeetingServiceImpl(MeetingRepository meetingRepository, EmployeeRepository employeeRepository,
                              VisitorRepository visitorRepository) {
        this.meetingRepository = meetingRepository;
        this.employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        this.visitorRepository = visitorRepository;
    }

    private Meeting mapToMeeting(MeetingDto meetingDto) {
        return Meeting.builder()
                .id(meetingDto.getId())
                .contentOfMeeting(meetingDto.getContentOfMeeting())
                .startOfMeeting(meetingDto.getStartOfMeeting())
                .endOfMeeting(meetingDto.getEndOfMeeting())
                .status(Status.valueOf(String.valueOf(Status.REJECTED)))
                .employees(meetingDto.getEmployees())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void createMeeting(Long visitorId, MeetingDto meetingDto) {
        Visitor visitor = visitorRepository.findById(visitorId).orElse(null);
        Meeting meeting = mapToMeeting(meetingDto);
        meeting.setVisitor(visitor);
        meeting.setEmployees(meetingDto.getEmployees());
        meetingRepository.save(meeting);
    }
}
```

And my template for GetMapping:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create a meeting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l"
          crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h3>Create a meeting</h3>
    <hr/>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/visitors/new-meeting}" th:object="${meeting}" method="post">
        <p>Content: <input type="text" id="content" name="content" th:field="*{contentOfMeeting}" placeholder="Content"></p>
        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('contentOfMeeting')}" class="text-danger" th:errors="*{contentOfMeeting}"></p>
        <p>Start of meeting: <input type="datetime-local" id="start" name="start" th:field="*{startOfMeeting}" placeholder="Start of meeting"></p>
        <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('startOfMeeting')}" class="text-danger" th:errors="*{startOfMeeting}"></p>
        <p>End of meeting: <input type="datetime-local" id="end" name="email" th:field="*{endOfMeeting}" placeholder="End of meeting"></p>
        <p></pd><span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('endOfMeeting')}" th:errors="*{endOfMeeting}" class="text-danger">End of meeting can not be before start of meeting</span></p>
        <label>Employees: </label>
        <p>To select more than one employee please click ctrl</p>
        <select id="employee" class="form-control" th:field="${employeeList}" multiple name="employeeList">
            <option th:each="employee : ${employeeList}" th:value="${employee.id}" th:text="${employee.name + ' ' + employee.surname}"></option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
        <br>
        <h6><a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a></h6>
        <br>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you be so kind to take a look and help me to solve the issue?

I tried refactor template and controller but the problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I solved the issue with this changes in ServiceImpl:

```
@Override
public void createMeeting(Long visitorId, MeetingDto meetingDto) {
    Visitor visitor = visitorRepository.findById(visitorId).orElse(null);
    Meeting meeting = mapToMeeting(meetingDto);
    meeting.setVisitor(visitor);
    List<Employee> selectedEmployees = employeeRepository.findAllById(meetingDto.getEmployeeIds());
    meeting.setEmployees(selectedEmployees);
    for (Employee employee : selectedEmployees) {
        employee.getMeeting().add(meeting);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your support @NaveenNegi.